# Change texture on SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I have an SKSpriteNode and I want to change the texture on it when the user touches the screen. But cannot work out how to do so.

Creating and adding the head. (Declared in header).

```
    head = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",face]];
    head.position = CGPointMake(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    [self addChild:head];
```

When a touch is detected, the below is run, but I cannot work out how to apply it to the SKSpritenode?!

```
            SKAction* changeFace = [SKAction setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",face]]];
            [self runAction:changeFace];
```

I have tried the below also, but it does not seem to work...

```
            head.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",face]];
```

Hope somebody is able to point me in the correct direction!

Comment: "does not seem to work" ... so it does actually work but it only seems like it doesn't? Describe what's happening. And check that you'r loading the correct file and texture isn't nil.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run the action on the scene (or any other object than your sprite.) The second code should work however, but using the SKAction try this instead.

```
[head runAction:changeFace];
```

Answer (score 11):

I have it working here, look at the code below:

1 - Create the SKSpriteNode

```
self.ninja = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ninja1"];
self.ninja.position = CGPointMake(self.ninja.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
[self addChild:self.ninja];
```

2 - Change the texture:

```
self.ninja.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"ninja2"];
```

Obs: I change the texture in touchesBegan event, but this should work in any way you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

I also experiencing this one, I was able to change texture but the the texture is stretch.
What is causing this?

Comment: try this after you change the texture

self.size = self.texture.size;

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SKAction*animation=[SKAction animateWithTextures:actions timePerFrame:0.1 resize:NO restore:YES];
```